# iOS Call Screen Capability

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios10

I'm trying to build an App with video calling capabilities like Skype and I'm trying to figure out how to make it ring with the native call screen as Skype, Hangouts and several other big apps do.

Are those APIs public? If so what are they called/where can I find the documentation on them?

Thanks

Comment: They're in CallKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes CallKit allows yoy to use native UI to provide Voip calling for your app. However you need to be aware that connection and calling itself must be implemented on your own.